# Unable to execute tests from command line via xcodebuild on Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, command-line, jenkins

I'm using the following command to execute the tests:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1'
```

This works fine locally, however when I try this on Jenkins it fails with the following error:

> xcodebuild test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1'
>
> xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination
>   specifier:        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 }
>
> The requested device could not be found because no available devices
>   matched the request.
>
> Available destinations for the "MyScheme" scheme:
>
> Build step
>   'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

So I launched Xcode GUI on Jenkins to check if the iPhone 6 simulator is present, and it's there. Another interesting thing is when I run the same xcodebuild command without specifying the name and the OS for the destination on my local, I get the list of all available simulators, like so:

> Available destinations for the "MyScheme" scheme:         { platform:iOS
>   Simulator, id:683233C4-EC2B-48A3-826B-10EF62A875CD, OS:8.1, name:iPad
>   2 }       { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:6358A6F5-2FD0-4377-BD32-0A2C3329276D, OS:8.1, name:iPad Air }      {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:224533ED-94DA-46CC-B1DB-1781A1C80710,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPad Retina }        { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:D114BC7E-A913-4063-A349-C119BAFC06DA, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 4s }         {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:7AF6D6F4-C6BC-4A47-B83C-3A4B43ABE0DD,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPhone 5 }       { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:BE82D607-466A-43E5-863D-6A05F217C117, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 5s }         {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:0AFCC9AB-7C59-48C7-9BFB-FBF4865B7A63,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 Plus }      { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:D183FF05-3023-4FB5-BEA0-290EA881040A, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 }      {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:26038DBD-791C-421E-99F4-9153CA726A2F,
>   OS:8.1, name:Resizable iPad }         { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:31B2F0AE-3547-4189-A561-CD2088F6C645, OS:8.1, name:Resizable iPhone
>   }

But when I do the same on the Jenkins, this list is empty.

I'm using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) on both local and Jenkins, my schemes are properly shared so I can see them in the GUI when I launch it on the Jenkins. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using workspace cleanup plugin and I remove all derived data before build on Jenkins.

**Edit:**
I discovered that when prepending the destination value with *generic/* I get the proper simulator list on the Jenkins, it still complains that I couldn't find the simulator to run on, even though the one I used is on the list:

> xcodebuild test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme
>   -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1'
>
> xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided
>   destination specifier:        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:8.1, name:iPhone
>   6 }
>
> The requested device could not be found because no available devices
>   matched the request.
>
> Available destinations for the "MyScheme" scheme:       {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:20D0A659-A25A-40E1-9C11-FC6ECA004012,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPad 2 }         { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:7B5DF104-BE34-415F-8818-3907B6CB9C63, OS:8.1, name:iPad Air }      {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:2DDF024E-811D-4D93-BD8E-EF34BFC9D8CA,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPad Retina }        { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:FFE95D35-B9DD-449E-83D0-50777BF5B783, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 4s }         {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:EF5A0D8A-6A1F-492C-B451-8F3B8B5EC5EE,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPhone 5 }       { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:A1FCF8DA-BD9F-4ABC-8E0A-4B8547362274, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 5s }         {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:1B75E350-7FC8-4407-8116-F3674F3AC187,
>   OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 Plus }      { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:694CAA87-765D-4FDF-8B27-75E5B537F48E, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 }      {
>   platform:iOS Simulator, id:FF5588C0-14B5-4303-A2AC-9ACF63B1852C,
>   OS:8.1, name:Resizable iPad }         { platform:iOS Simulator,
>   id:E402C9C9-97BA-4909-96B3-3D3C7F6CCC3B, OS:8.1, name:Resizable iPhone
>   }
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Jenkins was using a user that didn't have enough permissions. I figured it out when I created another job and tried to sign the archive. By default, Jenkins uses 'jenkins' user to do stuff, but if you ssh or screen share to your build server with other user, than you are screwed. I decided to remove my Jenkins daemon and instead use [JenkinsApp](https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app).